# Button tag not working in IE 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-7

I have form that takes input and i have submit button and reset input type... i have issue with submit button tag in IE 7, all rest of browser and IE version >7 working fine...

here is my code ...

```
 <form id="form_searchProperty" action="../jQuery Search Engine/searchPage01.html">

    //input tag for form value 

   <div class="submitCriteria">
       <button class="button_submit" >Search</button>
       <input class="button_reset" type="reset" />
   </div>

 </form>
```

jQuery function

```
     $("#form_searchProperty").submit(function () {

       var givenCriteria = $(this).serializeArray();

      });
```

Comment: Not sure I get it? A button inside a form will submit the form, so you need to prevent that, but your javascript function doesn't really do anything? What seems to be the problem!

Comment: You forget to define `type="submit"` for button...Its IE you must not forget this.

Comment: sorry my fault i totally miss out type in button

Answer (score 5):

Use the type submit,

```
<button class="button_submit" type='submit' >Search</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

`<button>` does NOT submit forms unless you tell it to - at least, it's not supposed to. It does in some browsers, for some annoying reason.

Why not use an actual submit button?

```
<input type="submit" class="button_submit" value="Search" />
```

Comment: It actually does in all browsers, except old IE !

Comment: yh that true ... i was struggling with IE 7